# How to get the data from specific index in json file java

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

`JSONParser` parses all json objects in a given file but i want to parse json objects starting from **100th** **index** to end of the file.

I can do this later using `subList` but if I have **1 Million** json objects in my json file I dont want to parse everything because efficiency will be reduced.

```
public static void readJsonFile() {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\2018-4-21.json"));

        for (Object o : a.subList(100,a.size())) {
            JSONObject checkIn = (JSONObject) o;

            String userId = (String) checkIn.get("UserID");
            System.out.print(userId);

            String inout = (String) checkIn.get("INOUT");
            System.out.print("   " + inout);

            String swippedDateTime = (String) checkIn.get("SwippedDateTime");
            System.out.print("   " + swippedDateTime);

            System.out.println("");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## My Json File

```
[
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:25"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:36"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:36"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:36"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:38"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:38"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:38"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:39"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:39"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:39"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:42"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:42"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:42"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:42"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:42"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:42"
    },
    {
        "UserID": "2",
        "INOUT": null,
        "SwippedDateTime": "2018-4-23 22:49"
    }
]
```

Comment: Why is your question text formatted as headers? Stop that! And please format code correctly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "efficiency will be reduced"? (I agree, but I would like to know exactly what you are concerned about)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to locate index 100, is to *parse* everything up to index 100.

I think what you're *really* asking, is how to do that without creating unnecessary objects in memory.

The answer to that can actually also help you manage files with millions of records, without running out of memory:

**Use a *streaming* parser.**

With a streaming parser, you will get the data as it is parsed, so you can quickly skip the first X records, then begin processing records one at a time, so you never have to keep more than one record in memory.

That mean you can actually parse files of unlimited size, with a very small memory footprint.

Since you're using GSON, that means you need to use [`JsonReader`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) instead of [`JsonParser`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1,000,000 records then memory usage is a concern.

The most efficient way to do this is to manually read past the first part of the file -- in the case you have shown, all your records are the same size, so you could simply use `InputStream.skip()` -- of course if your String fields like `UserID` can be different lengths then this won't work.

You could read the file character by character, counting (say) the commas to determine when you've skipped 100 records.

After you've skipped the first part of the file, you should use a streaming parser to read the rest. Gson will do that: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

You can also use a streaming parser to efficiently skip the first part of your file.

Comment: counting commas might not work in all cases what if i have String which contains comma

Comment: Yes, that would only work if your data is predictable -- I would simply use the streaming parser to skip.